# How to put yaxis in the middle of plot in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hell guys

I have to put the y-axis in the middle of my chart with ggplot.

This is my code:

```
ggplot(mtcars,aes(cyl,mpg))+geom_point()+scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-8,8))
```

Now, how I move the y-axis to the `x = 0` point?

I thought about create a "fake" axis with, `annotate()`, `vline()`, but I dont think this is to clever.

**Any suggestion? It would be great if the solutiondont use any other package. Only ggplot.**

Any help?

Comment: Answers in possible duplicates do similar to what you propose: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17753101/center-x-and-y-axis-with-ggplot2 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62345433/how-to-center-axes-in-ggplot2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
ggplot(mtcars,aes(cyl,mpg)) + 
 geom_point() + 
 scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-8,8)) + 
 geom_vline(xintercept = 0) + 
 geom_hline(yintercept = 0)
```

for this plot

[image]

Also look at the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17753101/center-x-and-y-axis-with-ggplot2), if you want ticks and labels on the lines.