# How to reposition y axis and its labels at the center (x = 0) in a mirror plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've made a mirror plot with positive and negative values. Now I want to place Y axis and labels in the center between red and green bars (where x = 0).
The code for plot is following:

```
ggplot() +                
  geom_bar(data = upreg_match, aes(x=Up,y=BIN_names),  
             fill = "yellowgreen", color = "black", stat = "identity")+ 
  geom_bar(data = downreg_match, aes(x=Down,y=BIN_names),  
             fill = "tomato3", color = "black", stat = "identity")+ 
  labs(x = "", y = "")+ 
  ggtitle("Controls") +
  theme_bw()
```

Resulted figure is following:

[image]

Unfortunately, I cannot find anything in the Internet.

Comment: Here are some approaches from a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62345433/how-to-center-axes-in-ggplot2

Comment: Thank you very much, it works, but it only adds y axis at 0 position, but not place labels right between green and red bars

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)
df1 <- data.frame(Manufacturer = stringr::str_to_title(unique(mpg$manufacturer)), 
                  Value = sample(c(-1, -2, 0, 1, 2), size = 15, replace = TRUE))


ggplot(df1) +                
  geom_bar(aes(x = Value, y = Manufacturer, fill = as.factor(sign(Value))),  
           color = "black", stat = "identity", show.legend = FALSE) + 
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0) +
  geom_label(aes(x = 0, y = Manufacturer, label = Manufacturer), alpha = 0.5) +
  labs(title = "Example", x = "", y = "") + 
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-03-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score -1):

Maybe something like this?

```
library(patchwork)

settings <- list(theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(),
                       axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
                       axis.title.y = element_blank()),
                 scale_fill_gradient(low = "yellowgreen", 
                                     high = "tomato3", guide = "none"))

(ggplot(df1) +
  geom_col(aes(pmin(0, Value), Manufacturer, fill = sign(Value))) + settings) + 
(ggplot(df1) +
  geom_col(aes(pmax(0, Value), Manufacturer, fill = sign(Value))) + settings + 
   theme(axis.text.y = element_text(hjust = 0.5)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works great with minor modifications :)